# find all prime numbers from given range python

Tags: python

Output should be as follows:

Give the lower bound of the number range: 0

Give the upper bound of the number range: 1

0 cannot be prime.

1 cannot be prime.

Could not find primes from the test range.

Give the lower bound of the number range: 0

Give the upper bound of the number range: 20

0 cannot be prime.

1 cannot be prime.

2 is a prime.

3 is a prime.

4 is not a prime, because 2 * 2 = 4

5 is a prime.

6 is not a prime, because 2 * 3 = 6

7 is a prime.

8 is not a prime, because 2 * 4 = 8

9 is not a prime, because 3 * 3 = 9

10 is not a prime, because 2 * 5 = 10

11 is a prime.

12 is not a prime, because 2 * 6 = 12

13 is a prime.

14 is not a prime, because 2 * 7 = 14

15 is not a prime, because 3 * 5 = 15

16 is not a prime, because 2 * 8 = 16

17 is a prime.

18 is not a prime, because 2 * 9 = 18

19 is a prime.

20 is not a prime, because 2 * 10 = 20

Searched 21 numbers, from which 8 were primes.

The last found prime was 19.

```
low = input("Give the lower bound of the number range: ")
high = input("Give the upper bound of the number range: ")
low = int(low)
high = int(high)
for n in range(low,high):
    if n<2:
        print (n, "cannot be prime.")


for n in range(low,high):
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n % x == 0: # is n divisible with x? If yes, not a prime
            y = n//x*x
            print(n, "is not a prime, because", x, "*", n//x, "=", y)
            break #this breaks the inner loop, and we continue with the outer!

        else:
            print(n, "is a prime.")
            break
```

The code is not successfully running
It shows the output:

Give the lower bound of the number range: 0↩

Give the upper bound of the number range: 20↩

0 cannot be prime.↩

1 cannot be prime.↩

3 is a prime.↩

4 is not a prime, because 2 * 2 = 4↩

5 is a prime.↩

6 is not a prime, because 2 * 3 = 6↩

7 is a prime.↩

8 is not a prime, because 2 * 4 = 8↩

9 is a prime.↩

10 is not a prime, because 2 * 5 = 10↩

11 is a prime.↩

12 is not a prime, because 2 * 6 = 12↩

13 is a prime.↩

14 is not a prime, because 2 * 7 = 14↩

15 is a prime.↩

16 is not a prime, because 2 * 8 = 16↩

17 is a prime.↩

18 is not a prime, because 2 * 9 = 18↩

19 is a prime.

Comment: *The code is not successfully running*, why? what happens? what is the output? is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if `n` is divisible by all numbers between 2 and `n`, since you exit the inner for loop after the first iteretion in both cases (when `n` divisible by `x` and when it is not).

To fix it, you need to move the `else` block to the outer loop (so it will run only when you don't exit the loop, meaning `n` is prime), and only break when `n` is not prime.

```
low = input("Give the lower bound of the number range: ")
high = input("Give the upper bound of the number range: ")
low = int(low)
high = int(high)
for n in range(low,high):
    if n<2:
        print (n, "cannot be prime.")


for n in range(low,high):
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n % x == 0: # is n divisible with x? If yes, not a prime
            y = n//x*x
            print(n, "is not a prime, because", x, "*", n//x, "=", y)
            break #this breaks the inner loop, and we continue with the outer!

    else:
        print(n, "is a prime.")
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this one works for 0-20 range

```
low = input("Give the lower bound of the number range: ")
high = input("Give the upper bound of the number range: ")
low = int(low)
high = int(high)

for n in range(low, high+1):
    if n <= 1:
        print(n, "cannot be prime")
    elif n == 2 or n == 3:
        print(n, "is a prime")
    elif n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        print(n, "is not a prime")
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime")
```